# Navigation bar side by side in Django?

Tags: html, css, django

I'm trying to build a navigation bar for practice but running into an issue. I'm trying to get information from views.py to share on website through html but not working very well. It displays the content perfectly but it is not showing them in one line. I included a picture of the rendered website.

HTML Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
 ul{
   width : 100%;
   float : left;
   display: inline-block;
   list-style-type: none;
   background-color: blue;
 }
</style>

<head>
  <title>Coding for fun</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="navBar">
    {% for my_sub in my_test %}
    <li> {{ my_sub}} </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `inline` for `li` instead of `ul`.

Change your `<style>` to below.

```
ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

It will work fine.

Comment: That worked perfectly! but would it have worked as well if i used ```.navBar``` instead of ```ul li```? Or would that be considered not best practices?

Comment: Yeah you could have used `.navbar li { display: inline-block;}` also.

Comment: okay i think i understand. Is there a reason for the gap above the nav bar? I will as soon as 10 mins pass so i can accept answer!

Comment: I think you can see that by inspecting the element into browser what css is causing that gap.